# How to read stix data from hail a taxii

Tags: go

Want to read stix data from http://hailataxii.com/ but not getting the idea to get that!!

For how to connect they have provided not much info and haven't found any documentation regarding it. Thought of using freetaxiiserver (Go package) getting an error while installing it. https://github.com/freetaxii/server#freetaxiiserver

```
go get -u -v github.com/freetaxii/server/cmd/freetaxii
cd github.com/freetaxii/server/cmd/freetaxii
```

**Error**
1] for first command

```
package github.com/freetaxii/libstix2/resources/collections: cannot find package "github.com/freetaxii/libstix2/resources/collections" in any of:
    /usr/local/go/src/github.com/freetaxii/libstix2/resources/collections (from $GOROOT)
    /home/rohith/go/src/github.com/freetaxii/libstix2/resources/collections (from $GOPATH)
package github.com/freetaxii/libstix2/objects/baseobject: cannot find package "github.com/freetaxii/libstix2/objects/baseobject" in any of:
    /usr/local/go/src/github.com/freetaxii/libstix2/objects/baseobject (from $GOROOT)
    /home/rohith/go/src/github.com/freetaxii/libstix2/objects/baseobject (from $GOPATH)
```

2] for the second command

```
bash: cd: github.com/freetaxii/server/cmd/freetaxii: No such file or directory
```

have installed its required dependency.

Is there any way to read data hailTaxii or if I get documentation will be helpfull.

Comment: check your go env and $GOPATH, because of error is cannot find package. so check your go env once

Comment: It is dependency issue; seems you not using go mod; You need to find if they using some dependency manager and use that to restore or you might need to manually fetch them and put it in right directory

Comment: `github.com/freetaxii/server/cmd/freetaxii` imports `github.com/freetaxii/libstix2/resources/collections` but it appears that this has been removed in the latest version of `libstix2` (its there in version 0.5.1) - see [this issue](https://github.com/freetaxii/server/issues/9). You could try manually retrieving the earlier version of `libstix2`.